# extract attribute values from XML file (starlet)

Tags: xmlstarlet

I have a small xml file with five entries in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="4" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="7" CreationDate="2008-07-31T21:42:52.667" Score="630" ViewCount="42817" Body="&lt;p&gt;I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;This is my code:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;&#xA;this.Opacity = trans;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;When I build the application, it gives the following error:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;blockquote&gt;&#xA;  &lt;p&gt;Cannot implicitly convert type &lt;code&gt;'decimal'&lt;/code&gt; to &lt;code&gt;'double'&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I tried using &lt;code&gt;trans&lt;/code&gt; and &lt;code&gt;double&lt;/code&gt; but then the control doesn't work. This code worked fine in a past VB.NET project.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="8" LastEditorUserId="3641067" LastEditorDisplayName="Rich B" LastEditDate="2019-07-19T01:39:54.173" LastActivityDate="2019-07-19T01:39:54.173" Title="Convert Decimal to Double?" Tags="&lt;c#&gt;&lt;floating-point&gt;&lt;type-conversion&gt;&lt;double&gt;&lt;decimal&gt;" AnswerCount="13" CommentCount="2" FavoriteCount="48" CommunityOwnedDate="2012-10-31T16:42:47.213" />
  <row Id="6" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="31" CreationDate="2008-07-31T22:08:08.620" Score="281" ViewCount="18214" Body="&lt;p&gt;I have an absolutely positioned &lt;code&gt;div&lt;/code&gt; containing several children, one of which is a relatively positioned &lt;code&gt;div&lt;/code&gt;. When I use a &lt;code&gt;percentage-based width&lt;/code&gt; on the child &lt;code&gt;div&lt;/code&gt;, it collapses to &lt;code&gt;0 width&lt;/code&gt; on IE7, but not on Firefox or Safari.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;If I use &lt;code&gt;pixel width&lt;/code&gt;, it works. If the parent is relatively positioned, the percentage width on the child works.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;ol&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Is there something I'm missing here?&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Is there an easy fix for this besides the &lt;code&gt;pixel-based width&lt;/code&gt; on the&#xA;child?&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Is there an area of the CSS specification that covers this?&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ol&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="9" LastEditorUserId="3641067" LastEditorDisplayName="Rich B" LastEditDate="2019-07-19T01:43:04.077" LastActivityDate="2019-07-19T01:43:04.077" Title="Percentage width child element in absolutely positioned parent on Internet Explorer 7" Tags="&lt;html&gt;&lt;css&gt;&lt;internet-explorer-7&gt;" AnswerCount="6" CommentCount="0" FavoriteCount="10" />
  <row Id="7" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="4" CreationDate="2008-07-31T22:17:57.883" Score="425" Body="&lt;p&gt;An explicit cast to double like this isn't necessary:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;double trans = (double) trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Identifying the constant as &lt;code&gt;5000.0&lt;/code&gt; (or as &lt;code&gt;5000d&lt;/code&gt;) is sufficient:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;pre&gt;&lt;code&gt;double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;&#xA;double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000d;&#xA;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="9" LastEditorUserId="4020527" LastEditDate="2017-12-16T05:06:57.613" LastActivityDate="2017-12-16T05:06:57.613" CommentCount="0" />
  <row Id="9" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="1404" CreationDate="2008-07-31T23:40:59.743" Score="1742" ViewCount="555183" Body="&lt;p&gt;Given a &lt;code&gt;DateTime&lt;/code&gt; representing a person's birthday, how do I calculate their age in years?  &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="1" LastEditorUserId="3956566" LastEditorDisplayName="Rich B" LastEditDate="2018-04-21T17:48:14.477" LastActivityDate="2019-06-26T15:25:44.253" Title="How do I calculate someone's age in C#?" Tags="&lt;c#&gt;&lt;.net&gt;&lt;datetime&gt;" AnswerCount="63" CommentCount="5" FavoriteCount="436" CommunityOwnedDate="2011-08-16T19:40:43.080" />
  <row Id="11" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="1248" CreationDate="2008-07-31T23:55:37.967" Score="1444" ViewCount="149445" Body="&lt;p&gt;Given a specific &lt;code&gt;DateTime&lt;/code&gt; value, how do I display relative time, like:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;2 hours ago&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;3 days ago&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;a month ago&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="1" LastEditorUserId="6479704" LastEditorDisplayName="user2370523" LastEditDate="2017-06-04T15:51:19.780" LastActivityDate="2019-05-26T02:31:53.863" Title="Calculate relative time in C#" Tags="&lt;c#&gt;&lt;datetime&gt;&lt;time&gt;&lt;datediff&gt;&lt;relative-time-span&gt;" AnswerCount="37" CommentCount="3" FavoriteCount="539" CommunityOwnedDate="2009-09-04T13:15:59.820" />
</posts>
```

I am interested in extracting only the Title and Body from each of the 5 entries. The best I could come up so far is using starlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/posts/row' -v "concat(@Body,'|', @Title)" -n very_small_posts.xml
```

very_small_posts.xml is the xml file with the above 5 entries. The problem with this the output has XML tags in them and I see empty lines too. Like below (output of first row):

```
<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.</p>

<p>This is my code:</p>

<pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;
this.Opacity = trans;
</code></pre>

<p>When I build the application, it gives the following error:</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>Cannot implicitly convert type <code>'decimal'</code> to <code>'double'</code></p>
</blockquote>

<p>I tried using <code>trans</code> and <code>double</code> but then the control doesn't work. This code worked fine in a past VB.NET project.</p>
|Convert Decimal to Double?
```

Is there a way to clean them up? I want to see only regular text as output without any tags....and possibly with the attribute names preceding the values. I do not want to see `<p>, </p>, <blockquote>`, ..in my output. Any suggestions?

Preferred output (for first row):

```
Body=I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity. This is my code: decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000; this.Opacity = trans; When I build the application, it gives the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'I tried using trans and double but then the control doesn't work. This code worked fine in a past VB.NET project.
Title=Convert Decimal to Double?
```

Answer (score 0):

A better answer after trying more:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/posts/row' -v "concat(@Body,'|', @Title, '||')" -n very_small_posts.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'

sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' will remove the xml tags.
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' will remove the empty lines.
```

Note that I added '||' to the end so I know where the end is for each row of extraction.

Answer (score 0):

If the output sample (containing tags) in your original posting were
in an XML file it would be easy to extract the normalized text, so to
produce the desired output make and query an XML wrapper:

```shell
xmlstarlet sel -t \
-e doc \
  -m 'posts/row' \
    -e Body -v '@Body' -b \
    -e Title -v '@Title' -b \
file.xml |
xmlstarlet unesc |
xmlstarlet sel --text -t -m '*/*' -v 'concat(name(),"=",normalize-space())' --nl
```

where:

- 1st `sel` creates container elements around `@Body` and `@Title` contents
- `unesc` converts XML character entities, such as `&lt;` to `<`
- 2nd `sel` extracts second-level elements as normalized text prefixed
  with element name

Using `unesc` this way to modify document structure is certainly not
advised but it's doable when controlled.

[Link](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/) to `xmlstarlet` user's guide.